# How to 301 a folder on an old domain to new domain and then individually 301 sub folders to the new domain?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, http-redirect, redirect

I have some questions about a 301 redirect on an Apache server, this is redirecting from an old site.

OLD DOMAIN:

```
http://xx.xxxxx.xxxxx.com/folder
```

NEW DOMAIN:

```
http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com.au
```

In this case on the old domain my site sits entirely in the "folder" section of the site. I have galleries, articles etc all sitting in "folder" that I want to redirect on a page by page basis to the new site. There is in excess of 1000 pages to be redirected.

I have set up the old URLs and new URLs in an excel document and will prepare an entry to add to `.htaccess`, I want to be able to redirect the home page of the old site to the new domain, and then many of the key articles, galleries, categories on the old site to a totally new URL on the new domain.

The issue I think is the old domain has 250 links pointing to the home folder. If I simply redirect that folder to the new root domain, will I then be able to redirect all the sub folders independently, or does that redirect on the home folder cascade down through all of the folders, essentially redirecting everything to the new root domain?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Further to this post, i might have worked it out - would this be as simple as listing all of the specific URL redirects first, and then listing the general folder -> root redirect last. That way all of the individual redirects will be performed before the general folder-> root redirect.

Answer (score 0):

301 redirects via `.htaccess` files works on an order of precedence.  I outlined my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265940/htaccess-301-redirect-passing-along-old-url-to-new-url/19266671#19266671) which seems to be inline with your comment above.

Basically, your homepage should be the very last redirect b/c `.htaccess` will see that as a catch-all url.  If you list it first, then it will redirect every page to the homepage.  If you want a specific entry to got to a deeper url, then you you need to list that before your homepage redirect.