# Is it possible to redirect from our domain to a github repo using htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, github, redirect

Essentially, the title covers it but is it possible to redirect from our domain to a Github repo and a Github.io page using the htaccess file?

If not possible with an htaccess file is this possible at all?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265940/htaccess-301-redirect-passing-along-old-url-to-new-url/19266671?

Comment: you can simply add a 301 redirect from an oldlink? or just a forward slash if redirecting the entire site?

Redirect 301 /yourwebsitelink/ https://www.github.com/link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess 301 redirect passing along old url to new url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265940/htaccess-301-redirect-passing-along-old-url-to-new-url)